# What does the Candy Merchant's hat do?

Tags: candy-box-2

I can buy the Candy Merchant's hat for 1,000,000 candies. What does it do? Is it worth it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It multiplies the candy drops from quests by 7

Answer (score 0):

It multiplies the candies you get in quests by 7. so 1000x7=7000 candies. I think it is worth it.